# Function App not able to connect to Storage container

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am using Azure Python Function with consumption based model. In my Azure Function , I am trying to connect to storage account and download a file using code as below. It works when connecting to a storage container which is not behind a firewall , but fails to connect to storage…

```
     blob = BlobClient(account_url="https://"+StorageContName+".blob.core.windows.net",
              container_name=ContName+"/"+"mdhubinput",
              blob_name=filename+'.csv',
              credential=storagecred)
      stream = blob.download_blob()
```

Comment: One option is to put your Function app in the same VNET as your storage account and then add service endpoint on your subnet with Microsoft.Storage.

Comment: Refer this SO thread answers -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060121/azure-function-connection-to-azure-blob-storage-behind-vnet-issue

Comment: When you create a function app, you either create a new storage account or link to an existing storage account. During function app creation, you can secure a new storage account behind a virtual network and integrate the function app with this network. At this time, you can't secure an existing storage account being used by your function app in the same way. - Reference- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-networking-how-to?tabs=portal#restrict-your-storage-account-to-a-virtual-network

Comment: @SiddheshDesai The solution that you proposed works for consumption type app as well, as Consumption plans currently don't support virtual networks

Comment: No unfortunately it won't work for consumption based plan

Comment: For now the only solution, I can think of is to make your storage account public and access the blob via SAS token with minimum and required permissions.

Comment: With SAS token you can restrict the access to blob- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access storage account with Azure Function app that is behind the firewall. You need to enable VNET integration between your Function app and Storage account by referring the steps in this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-networking-how-to?tabs=portal#restrict-your-storage-account-to-a-virtual-network).

But the V-NET Integration feature is not available for Azure Functions Consumption based Plan. There's an on going feature request on the same refer [**here**](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/646#issuecomment-465801398).  For now the V-net integration is only available for Premium Plan.

If you want to continue using Consumption based plan for your Function app and still want to implement restrictions in accessing your storage account, You can make your storage account public and make use of SAS URL with limited permissions. I created one SAS URL with Full Access you can uncheck the permissions according to your requirement and then I used this SAS URL to access my storage account with Azure functions like below:-

[image]

[image]

**init.py Code:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        # Replace 'YOUR_SAS_URL' with the actual SAS URL of your Blob Storage container.
        sas_url = "https://siliconstrg540.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=xxxx07-xxxxp&sig=xxxxyxxxxDg0BbM%3D"
        
        # Create a BlobServiceClient with the SAS URL
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=sas_url)

        # You can use the BlobServiceClient to perform various operations on the blob storage.
        # For example, listing containers and blobs:

        containers_info = "data"
        containers = blob_service_client.list_containers()
        for container in containers:
            containers_info += f"Container Name: {container.name}\n"

            # List blobs in the container
            container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container.name)
            blobs = container_client.list_blobs()
            for blob in blobs:
                containers_info += f"Blob Name: {blob.name}\n"

        return func.HttpResponse(containers_info, status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error: {e}", status_code=500)
```

**Output:-**

[image]